# Interpreting explain and adding indices to improve query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a fairly complicated select statement built upon the [Chado schema](http://gmod.org/wiki/Chado_Tables) worked out that runs somewhat efficiently. It currently takes about 5 seconds to process my query using a subset of my data. The full data set will likely be over a hundred times larger, and I'm concerned compute time will be prohibitively slow. I've been advised to use indices to improve performance, but I'm not entirely sure what that will involve.

My query:

```
SELECT dbxref.accession, dbxrefprop.value, contact.name, biomaterial.description, bp1.value AS isolation_source, bp2.value AS specimen_collection_date,
bp3.value AS collection_location_name, bp4.value AS genotype, refeat.seqlen, string_agg(feat.name, ', ' order by feat.name) AS tranlation_type, refeat.residues
FROM featureloc
INNER JOIN feature srcfeat ON srcfeat.feature_id = featureloc.srcfeature_id 
INNER JOIN feature feat ON feat.feature_id = featureloc.feature_id 
RIGHT JOIN dbxref ON dbxref.dbxref_id = srcfeat.dbxref_id
INNER JOIN feature refeat ON refeat.dbxref_id = dbxref.dbxref_id
INNER JOIN dbxrefprop ON dbxrefprop.dbxref_id = dbxref.dbxref_id 
INNER JOIN biomaterial ON biomaterial.dbxref_id = dbxref.dbxref_id 
INNER JOIN biomaterialprop bp1 ON (bp1.biomaterial_id = biomaterial.biomaterial_id and bp1.type_id = 2916)
INNER JOIN biomaterialprop bp2 ON (bp2.biomaterial_id = biomaterial.biomaterial_id and bp2.type_id = 2917)
INNER JOIN biomaterialprop bp3 ON (bp3.biomaterial_id = biomaterial.biomaterial_id and bp3.type_id = 2918)
INNER JOIN biomaterialprop bp4 ON (bp4.biomaterial_id = biomaterial.biomaterial_id and bp4.type_id = 2919)
INNER JOIN contact ON contact.contact_id = biomaterial.biosourceprovider_id
GROUP BY dbxref.accession, dbxrefprop.value, contact.name, biomaterial.description, bp1.value, bp2.value, bp3.value, bp4.value, refeat.seqlen, refeat.residues
HAVING (bp1.value = 'Alveolar Macrophage')
ORDER BY dbxref.accession;
```

The explain output (without HAVING line):

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=627.81..631.98 rows=98 width=361)
   Group Key: dbxref.accession, dbxrefprop.value, contact.name, biomaterial.description, bp1.value, bp2.value, bp3.value, bp4.value, refeat.seqlen, refeat.residues
   ->  Sort  (cost=627.81..628.06 rows=98 width=361)
         Sort Key: dbxref.accession, dbxrefprop.value, contact.name, biomaterial.description, bp1.value, bp2.value, bp3.value, bp4.value, refeat.seqlen, refeat.residues
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.42..624.57 rows=98 width=361)
               Hash Cond: (biomaterial.biosourceprovider_id = contact.contact_id)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.11..614.92 rows=98 width=316)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.83..563.01 rows=98 width=344)
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.54..511.11 rows=98 width=332)
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.26..459.20 rows=98 width=320)
                                       ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.98..407.30 rows=98 width=308)
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..148.51 rows=98 width=309)
                                                   ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.84..88.36 rows=164 width=312)
                                                         Merge Cond: (refeat.dbxref_id = dbxrefprop.dbxref_id)
                                                         ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.56..188.11 rows=1400 width=296)
                                                               Merge Cond: (refeat.dbxref_id = biomaterial.dbxref_id)
                                                               ->  Index Scan using feature_idx1 on feature refeat  (cost=0.29..884.42 rows=11936 width=264)
                                                               ->  Index Scan using biomaterial_idx3 on biomaterial  (cost=0.28..63.28 rows=1400 width=32)
                                                         ->  Index Scan using dbxrefprop_idx1 on dbxrefprop  (cost=0.28..60.28 rows=1400 width=16)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using dbxref_pkey on dbxref  (cost=0.29..0.36 rows=1 width=21)
                                                         Index Cond: (dbxref_id = refeat.dbxref_id)
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..2.63 rows=1 width=15)
                                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..2.06 rows=1 width=16)
                                                         ->  Index Scan using feature_idx1 on feature srcfeat  (cost=0.29..0.46 rows=1 width=16)
                                                               Index Cond: (dbxref.dbxref_id = dbxref_id)
                                                         ->  Index Scan using featureloc_idx2 on featureloc  (cost=0.29..1.14 rows=46 width=16)
                                                               Index Cond: (srcfeature_id = srcfeat.feature_id)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using feature_pkey on feature feat  (cost=0.29..0.56 rows=1 width=15)
                                                         Index Cond: (feature_id = featureloc.feature_id)
                                       ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp1  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12)
                                             Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = biomaterial.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2916))
                                 ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp2  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12)
                                       Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = bp1.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2917))
                           ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp3  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12)
                                 Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = bp1.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2918))
                     ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp4  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12)
                           Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = bp1.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2919))
               ->  Hash  (cost=5.36..5.36 rows=236 width=61)
                     ->  Seq Scan on contact  (cost=0.00..5.36 rows=236 width=61)
```

Based on my limited understanding on interpreting explain output, the following lines are suspect:

```
->  Index Scan using feature_idx1 on feature refeat  (cost=0.29..884.42 rows=11936 width=264)
->  Index Scan using biomaterial_idx3 on biomaterial  (cost=0.28..63.28 rows=1400 width=32)
->  Index Scan using dbxrefprop_idx1 on dbxrefprop  (cost=0.28..60.28 rows=1400 width=16)
```

[This demonstration](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) (in MySQL) indicates that indexing involves assigning additional primary keys to improve the efficiency of finding joins. Here are my proposed changes:

```
ALTER TABLE feature
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (dbxref_id);
ALTER TABLE biomaterial
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (dbxref_id);
ALTER TABLE dbxrefprop
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (dbxref_id);
```

Note that dbxref_id is a foreign key in all three tables referencing the primary key of the dbxref table. Would this be a valid solution to improve compute time? Instead of altering the tables, what lines within the query could be changed to further improve my query? The inner joined feature table with "refeat" alias is necessary to prevent omissions where features are not linked via the featureloc table.

**Edit1**

The primary keys for each joined table are are follows: 
featureloc = featureloc_id, feature = feature_id, dbxref = dbxref_id, dbxrefprop = dbxrefprop_id, biomaterial = biomaterial_id, biomaterialprop = biomaterialprop_id, contact = contact_id.

Given a sample size of 1400, tables had the following number of rows:
featureloc = 10536, feature = 11936, dbxref = 15492, dbxrefprop = 1400, biomaterial = 1400, biomaterialprop = 5600, contact = 236. Note that some tables (dbxref) contain preloaded data.

**Edit2**

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=522.10..526.26 rows=98 width=361) (actual time=7899.696..10201.445 rows=1400 loops=1)
   Group Key: dbxref.accession, dbxrefprop.value, contact.name, biomaterial.description, bp1.value, bp2.value, bp3.value, bp4.value, refeat.seqlen, refeat.residues
   Buffers: shared hit=320702 read=1752
   ->  Sort  (cost=522.10..522.34 rows=98 width=361) (actual time=7899.664..7940.350 rows=10606 loops=1)
         Sort Key: dbxref.accession, dbxrefprop.value, contact.name, biomaterial.description, bp1.value, bp2.value, bp3.value, bp4.value, refeat.seqlen, refeat.residues
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3708kB
         Buffers: shared hit=244651 read=1752
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.42..518.86 rows=98 width=361) (actual time=0.406..5525.245 rows=10606 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (biomaterial.biosourceprovider_id = contact.contact_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=171364 read=847
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.11..509.20 rows=98 width=316) (actual time=0.141..5201.920 rows=10606 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=171362 read=846
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.83..457.29 rows=98 width=344) (actual time=0.138..4258.617 rows=10606 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=139485 read=821
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.54..405.39 rows=98 width=332) (actual time=0.135..3082.229 rows=10606 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=107577 read=803
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.26..353.48 rows=98 width=320) (actual time=0.130..2179.420 rows=10606 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=75654 read=786
                                       ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.98..301.58 rows=98 width=308) (actual time=0.102..1566.105 rows=10606 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=43748 read=773
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..148.51 rows=98 width=309) (actual time=0.042..332.126 rows=1400 loops=1)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=4283 read=96
                                                   ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.84..88.36 rows=164 width=312) (actual time=0.024..208.163 rows=1400 loops=1)
                                                         Merge Cond: (refeat.dbxref_id = dbxrefprop.dbxref_id)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=78 read=93
                                                         ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.56..188.11 rows=1400 width=296) (actual time=0.016..165.490 rows=1400 loops=1)
                                                               Merge Cond: (refeat.dbxref_id = biomaterial.dbxref_id)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=73 read=81
                                                               ->  Index Scan using feature_idx1 on feature refeat  (cost=0.29..884.42 rows=11936 width=264) (actual time=0.008..1.471 rows=1401 loops=1)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=68 read=66
                                                               ->  Index Scan using biomaterial_idx3 on biomaterial  (cost=0.28..63.28 rows=1400 width=32) (actual time=0.005..118.944 rows=1400 loops=1)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=5 read=15
                                                         ->  Index Scan using dbxrefprop_idx1 on dbxrefprop  (cost=0.28..60.28 rows=1400 width=16) (actual time=0.005..1.018 rows=1400 loops=1)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=5 read=12
                                                   ->  Index Scan using dbxref_pkey on dbxref  (cost=0.29..0.36 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.057..0.058 rows=1 loops=1400)
                                                         Index Cond: (dbxref_id = refeat.dbxref_id)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=4205 read=3
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..1.55 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=0.119..0.848 rows=8 loops=1400)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=39465 read=677
                                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..1.01 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.061..0.511 rows=8 loops=1400)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=8314 read=162
                                                         ->  Index Scan using feature_idx1 on feature srcfeat  (cost=0.29..0.46 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.057..0.110 rows=1 loops=1400)
                                                               Index Cond: (dbxref.dbxref_id = dbxref_id)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=4203 read=3
                                                         ->  Index Scan using featureloc_idx2 on featureloc  (cost=0.29..0.48 rows=8 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.088 rows=8 loops=1400)
                                                               Index Cond: (srcfeature_id = srcfeat.feature_id)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=4111 read=159
                                                   ->  Index Scan using feature_pkey on feature feat  (cost=0.29..0.53 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=0.021..0.028 rows=1 loops=10536)
                                                         Index Cond: (feature_id = featureloc.feature_id)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=31151 read=515
                                       ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp1  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.041..0.042 rows=1 loops=10606)
                                             Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = biomaterial.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2916))
                                             Buffers: shared hit=31906 read=13
                                 ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp2  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.065..0.077 rows=1 loops=10606)
                                       Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = bp1.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2917))
                                       Buffers: shared hit=31923 read=17
                           ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp3  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.042..0.050 rows=1 loops=10606)
                                 Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = bp1.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2918))
                                 Buffers: shared hit=31908 read=18
                     ->  Index Scan using biomaterialprop_c1 on biomaterialprop bp4  (cost=0.28..0.52 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.027..0.031 rows=1 loops=10606)
                           Index Cond: ((biomaterial_id = bp1.biomaterial_id) AND (type_id = 2919))
                           Buffers: shared hit=31877 read=25
               ->  Hash  (cost=5.36..5.36 rows=236 width=61) (actual time=0.254..0.254 rows=236 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 31kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1
                     ->  Seq Scan on contact  (cost=0.00..5.36 rows=236 width=61) (actual time=0.003..0.129 rows=236 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1
 Planning time: 160.551 ms
 Execution time: 10275.793 ms
```

The current table structure can be found [here](http://gmod.org/wiki/Chado_Tables). I have not made any changes to the schema.

Comment: Please add the indexes you currently have on the tables.

Comment: Also, please add the number of rows (order of) the tables are expected to have.

Comment: To clarify, I have not assigned any indices. Do you want the default primary keys dictated by the schema I'm using? I will try to estimate the number of rows per table.

Comment: We need the complete table and index definitions in SQL and the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query to answer this question.

Comment: Basically, you need supporting indexes for all your foreign keys. (and: most people don't like RIGHT JOINs, they are confusing. Try to avoid them)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll work on getting that extra information up soon. I can change the RIGHT JOIN to a LEFT JOIN if that's considered (more) standard.